# QueryDsl @QueryType value for ListPath?

Tags: java, querydsl

I want to use `querydsl` auto generation of an `@Entity` to a querydsl mapping class.

Problem: I have a `@Transient` field that I have to qualify with `@QueryType` in order to make querydsl pick it up for generation.

My goal is to generate a `ListPath<String, StringPath>`, but the `@QueryType` annotation is missing any list value type:

@Entity
public class MyDto {
public List myList;

```
  @Transient
  @QueryType(value = ???)
  public List<String> myTransientList;
```

}

The first list is generated properly to `public final ListPath<String, StringPath> myList`.

But how can I also include the 2nd list?

Comment: If its transient, what is Querydsl supposed to map to? What is the underlying data model?

Comment: I want to use it in a `org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslBinderCustomizer` which requires a mapped `EntityPath` object. The transient `myTransientList` should then be converted to a customization similar to `root.myfield.in(value)`. Means, it triggers an `IN CLAUSE`.

Comment: But `String` is not an entity, and `myTransientList` is not even a managed property. `ListPaths` only work on `@ElementCollection` and `OneToMany` fields.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Not with just a `QueryType` at least. You probably need to write up some custom expression types and entity types.